# Treating NaN as 0 when adding and NaN when dividing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sparse dataframe where I need to do some column operations involving adding and weighted averaging.

```
df
     A   B   C    D   E   F
0  NaN NaN NaN   30  15  25  
1  15  25   35  NaN NaN NaN 
2  NaN NaN NaN   35  10  15
3  10  20   35  NaN NaN NaN
```

Now I have to create three new columns where one is `(A + D)`, one is `((A * B) + (D * E)) / (A + D)`, and the last one is  `((A * B * C) + (D * E * F)) / ((A * B) + (D * E))`. The problem I am having is that when I treat NaN as 0 then when I divide I get errors because you cant divide by 0 but when I perform operations with NaN then my result is NaN. I tried just writing a conditional but I get an error because its a column so that doesnt work. I didnt want to do it a row at a time because speed matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output when a number is divided by `NaN`? Is it `NaN`?

Comment: Yes, would it help if I added a result data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I read in your data and used `.fillna(0)` to replace `NaN` values. Is that an option?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard().fillna(0)
df

    A       B       C       D       E       F
0   0.0     0.0     0.0     30.0    15.0    25.0
1   15.0    25.0    35.0    0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0     35.0    10.0    15.0
3   10.0    20.0    35.0    0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Then I simply inputted your formulas:

```
df['G'] = (df['A'] + df['D'])
df['H'] = ((df['A'] * df['B']) + (df['D'] * df['E'])) / (df['A'] + df['D'])
df['I'] = ((df['A'] * df['B'] * df['C']) + (df['D'] * df['E'] * df['F'])) / ((df['A'] * df['B']) + (df['C'] * df['D']))
df
```

Is this what you are expecting below?

```
    A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I
0   0.0     0.0     0.0     30.0    15.0    25.0    30.0    15.0    inf
1   15.0    25.0    35.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     15.0    25.0    35.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0     35.0    10.0    15.0    35.0    10.0    inf
3   10.0    20.0    35.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     10.0    20.0    35.0
```

Finally, if you want to change `inf` values to nan values, you can use `df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)`

Comment: The issue is sometimes the whole row is NaN so I end up dividing by 0. When I divide by 0 I get an error. Is there a way to divide by 0 and get ```inf```. If I had infintity I could always replace them after I finish the computations